# How to pass another parameter in limit of cakephp 3.2

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.x, cakephp-3.2

I am using data table inbuilt ajax custom pagination.

Here i need to pass 2 parameter in limit function .

I need some help to make it possible .I am using cakephp 3.2.

Below is my code.

```html
$sql.=" ORDER BY ". $columns[$requestData['order'][0]['column']]."   ".$requestData['order'][0]['dir']."  LIMIT ".$requestData['start']." ,".$requestData['length']."   ";


This code is in core php ,

I want to convert it into cakephp .

Below is what i have tried so far.

 $order=$requestData['order'][0]['dir'];  //descending ya ascending
        $id=$columns[$requestData['order'][0]['column']];///order by which column


 $query=  $this->Orders->find('all')->where($condition)->limit($requestData['length'])->order(['Orders.'. $id.' '.$order]);

How can i write  this code  LIMIT ".$requestData['start']." ,".$requestData['length']."   ";

Using cakephp ,
In limit how to give both the limit as well as the start parameter($requestData['start']).
```

Eventually ,this is the end of my problem.
 Thank you any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Limit, it supports two parameters if you pass only one then it is limit parameter, and offset is 0 by default

```
LIMIT 10 //returns first 10 records only
```

If you pass two parameters then first is offset and second is limit

```
LIMIT 50, 10 //returns 10 records from 51st record
```

for passing offset in CakePHP query you can use `offset($start)` method or `page($page_number)` method Check [DOC](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#selecting-data)

Your Code Should be

```
$query=  $this->Orders->find('all')->where($condition)->limit($requestData['length'])->offset($requestData['start'])->order(['Orders.'. $id.' '.$order]);
```

Comment: wow ,its  really working .
Thank you a lot ,you save my time.
:) :) ;)

Comment: WOW... seriously? ;)

Comment: yes ,i have done it in page()  ,but i need the offset one .
I got to know it and thank you again. ;) ;) ;) :)

Answer (score 1):

There is an offset function in cakephp query that you can use

So your query becomes as below

$query=  $this->Orders->find('all')->where($condition)->offset($requestData['start'])->limit($requestData['length'])->order(['Orders.'. $id.' '.$order]);

This should work as required, it is same as start in the mysql query.